FX modelling in the real-world measure, $\mathbb{P}$ and its correlation to indices
So I am looking to model FX pairs in the real world measure $\mathbb{P}$ and their relationship to indices. From what I understand, if we have an FX, say EURUSD, the price will trend with the forward rate. So if $r_d < r_f$, EURUSD will rise at the difference of their rates, $(r_f - r_d)/252$ on $T+1$ days, whilst $3*(r_f - r_d)/252$ on their $T+2$ day. And so any movement outside of this price change is market action by traders.
Now from historical observations, we see that major FX pairs (and EURUSD in this case) are typically not martingales, and are like a CIR model with a time-varying mean-reversion level, which in this case, would be the difference in $r_f$ and $r_d$.
If we wanted to measure the intraday correlation of the FX pair, $F_t$ and an index, $S_t$, where index has a local interest-rate $r_l$, would it make sense to then remove(discount) the forward rate, which "isolates" and only leaves the impact of the market's perception on the FX pair, then measure the correlation? So if we had $t=1$-minute OHLC data points (using close prices), the index future trades for 20-hour days, it is a $T+1$ day, the FX settlement time was during the 20 hour period and no dividend payout during the period, then the measurement of the correlation would be:
$$dS_{t+1}=S_{t+1} - S_t$$
$$dF_{t+1}=F_{t+1} - F_t, \quad \text{if}\quad t\neq t_{\text{settlement}}$$
$$dF_{t+1}=e^{\frac{r_d-r_f}{252}}(F_{t+1} - F_t), \quad \text{if}\quad t= t_{\text{settlement}}$$
$$\therefore \Sigma = cov(dS_t, dF_t)$$
Which is affectively removing the price adjustment during the settlement window at 10pm UK time.
Extra: If $S_t$ was instead the spot index (I understand the spot technically doesn't exist), but then would $dS_{t+1}$ be (assuming a 6.5 hour trading day) given by:
$$dS_{t+1}=e^{\frac{r_l}{252\cdot 6.5 \cdot 60}}(S_{t+1} - S_t)?$$

What's the time unit of the covariance matrix ? I'm not clear if you have A) two different covariance matrices or  B) only one matrix but the elements are calculated differently depending on $t$. and why doesn't spot exist ?

@markleeds updated. $t=1$ minute increments and there is only 1 matrix. $\Sigma$ is just the sample covariance matrix calculated from all the 1 minute increments of the adjusted $dS$ and $dF$. You can’t trade the spot, it doesn’t exist. Only way to gain exposure is through an ETF or a futures contract. I only brought it up because the forward rate is baked into future’s price and so it won’t be changing wrt time, but I wanted an example where my stock process is drifting with the interest rate

@markleeds rather than an index, the 2nd example could be $AAPL spot. Ignoring dividends, the price on a minute by minute basis will drift wrt the interest rate

Let me think about this some. I'll get back either way but uncertain whether I'll have anything useful to say. Hopefully others will chime in and offer suggestions-insights. This topic is not my field ( is this index arbitrage ? ) but it sounded interesting.

One bad question for now. Are you say that. all else being equal, the price of $AAPL in a foreign country will drift because of the EURUSD currency movement ?

@markleeds Not index arb, but very similar. I don't want to give away too many hints what I am trading as it's quite a closed system where the alpha will disappear quickly if too many people catch-on. I am just trying to find a way to use FX as a predictive measurement.

No problem. I'm just trying to refresh myself on currencies because it's been quite a long time. But am I correct about my question on AAPL as far as why it drifts ?

AAPL doesn't need to drift at all - apart from interest rates, if you subscribe to the fact that the discounted price is a martingale. The reason an FX pair can trend in a direction is because 1 side of the pair has a higher interest-rate on average (covered interest arbitrage). What I am trying to figure out is after discounting the FX pair to remove this trend at the settlement-time, would I also need to de-trend the spot for the same reason

okay. thanks. I'll keep reading my book and your new comments. Like I said, I doubt that I'll be able to add anything useful but I'll try, slowly.

Not to be a pest ( I'm offering very little help but a lot of questions !!!! ) but do you have the book "Foreign Exchange" by Tim Weithers. He has a nice chapter on spot-forward arbitrage where $F_t$ denotes the forward associated with the FX pair. So, based on what I read in that, it seems like you are trying to back out the spot rate ( asset price of the FX pair ) that should be existing in order that there be no spot-forward arbitrage. But that doesn't seem exactly right based on your description.  Let me know because it would be easier to communicate if you had it.

Also, if you're tired of my questions and getting zero out of this discussion, then I understand and won't be offended if you don't want to continue to communicate ? It's an interesting problem and the dusty book I pulled out of my closet isn't bad either.
